# How to put drop down list of content type page in to another content type pages

Tags: views, nodes

I have crated two content type like A and B .some of field are similar .I don't want to repeat that field .I want to put drop down list on any one of A or B.

Comment: have u tried existing field in manage field ?

Comment: No I don't have idea of that

Comment: check the first part of the answer

Comment: got the thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOU should use the [entity reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MewHc.png) module for the above purpose.

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
>
> A generic entity reference field Four widgets: Two implemented on top
>   of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes), Two autocomplete
>   widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with
>   comma-separated entries in the same text field) Two formatters: A
>   "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the
>   referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.) A "Rendered
>   entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a
>   configurable view mode Integration with Views (for both forward and
>   backward references) Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a
>   consequence with Search API and the like) Integration with Devel
>   generate Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data
>   import This modules depends on Entity API and CTools.
>
> Modules extending Entity reference functionality:

**Earlier answer deleted following comments :**

If you want to use the existing field then just go to manage fields tab under 
**Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » A**
 and use existing field option where you will get the existing field of other content type
Check the image below for existing field option :
[image]

Or else you can do it in the following way :

You can get your dropdown list for content type in `$form_state['values']['your_field_name_for_dropdown']` and 

and Save that value in `$_SESSION['module_name']['your_field_name_for_dropdown']`
After saving that value you can use that value to insert into another content type in the hook_form_alter function or your custom_form itself.

Comment: ok but I dont want to add content of that field second time .what ever I added in side A it should be all display on B as drop down list.

Comment: that is why you should use existing field so that you dont need to add again

Comment: Suppose I have added five page in one content type A,all information is should be display as drop down list in content type B pages, from that I select any of them

Comment: so do you mean you want the content type as options?

Comment: Yes I need content type option

Comment: you should use node reference i will update the answer

Comment: there is five field  in side content type A ,If I selected any one page in side Content's type page of B is only display name of content page content not all field of content

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to `/admin/structure/types/manage/<your-content-type>/fields` and at the end of page you will find a 2 options : `Add new field`, and `Add existing field`

Use `Add existing field` to add a field from one content type in another content type.